# "Observing without judging" -- is there a Jewish basis for this concept?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, chazal

I have bumped into a concept attributed to the philosopher J. Krishnamurti:

> "observing without evaluating is the highest form of human
> intelligence"

The idea under this is to [avoid judging and diagnosing](https://www.shortform.com/blog/observing-without-evaluating/), which is often harmful to human interaction.

My question is: I believe I have encountered parallel proposals in Chazal. Can someone point me in some of those directions?

Comment: Rambam Moreh Nevuchim. שהטוב הוא במאמר שיפעל והרע במאמר שיתפעל כי כל התפעלות רע. Response is good and reaction is bad/evil, for all reaction (literally, where something has an affect on the observer) is bad/evil.

Comment: @pcoz Thank you! Can you point me where to find this in the source? (I am not sure if that is on sefaria?)

Comment: Not sure where this is in the Rambam, I heard it quoted by Rb Moshe Shapiro. On Google I only get one hit for this quote, page 95 in https://bit.ly/3gw00Wj

Comment: @pcoz I love the source (the PDF of the whole book can be downloaded), but I am struggling with: 1) How do I know that quote is from the Rambam? That book is primarily about the work of Judah Messer Leon; and 2) I find the language difficult to translate.

Comment: Avoiding diagnosing is not good if you want to help. Judgement is a part of misvot בצדק תשפוט עמיתך

Comment: Consider Leviticus 19:15  All effort is exerted by the justice to maintain impartiality before coming to judgement. This is explained further in H. Sanhedrin 21:1-4. Or on a related note consider H. Sanhedrin 20:1, where even though the witnesses observed an alleged assailant chase someon into a ruin and immediately saw him standing over a victim with a bloody sword, but they did not actually observe the defendant make a strike, the court may not convict.

Comment: he is talking about Zen stuff. watching with a thoughtless mind. animals and little children do this. watch out for these crazy people

Comment: @user813801 No, I am not talking about zen stuff. (If I was, I would say so)

Comment: @pcoz I can't find that quote in a useful source text so far. I am bummed, cause it is a good one!

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica The question is, where did Reb Moshe Shapiro get it from?

Comment: @pcoz I don't know. A friend (a scholar) took that quote and searched everything Bar Ilan has and came up empty handed. I am not able to understand the book on Google Books, so while I see the words, I do not understand the context or reference. So I am afraid I am nowhere (but I really like the quote! even if it is beyond my ability to translate)

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica "No, I am not talking about zen stuff" - you are not but he is

Answer (score 2):

The Jewish view is to judge others favorably as it says ([Leviticus 19:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.15?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en))

> You shall do no unrighteousness in judgment: thou shalt not respect
> the person of the poor, nor honour the person of the mighty: but **in
> righteousness shalt you judge your neighbour**.

In the words of R Avrohom Ehrman in his [Laws of interpersonal relationships](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/JTVH.html), pp. 14-20

> - the Torah commands us to give others the benefit of the doubt and to judge them favorably
> - if we see someone doing something that appears evil, we should search for extenuating circumstances, ways to excuse the suspicious
>   action and give it a favorable interpretation
> - it is nearly always possible to find some way to excuse, or at least to mitigate the severity of any action or bad quality one sees
> - as the Torah commands us ([Leviticus 19:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.18?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en)) we should love our neighbor as ourselves, i.e., we should give our neighbors the same
>   excuses we would give ourselves

You ask for sources in Chazal, here are a few

> - "Judge every man to the side of merit" ([Avot 1:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2165/jewish/Chapter-One.htm))
> - "Do not judge your fellow until you have stood in his place" ([Avot 2:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2011/jewish/Chapter-Two.htm))
> - “But in righteousness shall you judge your colleague,” that you should judge another favorably, and seek to find justification for his
>   actions, even if when interpreted differently his actions could be
>   judged unfavorably ([Shevuot 30a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.30a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) with R Steinsaltz'
>   interpretation)